# How to change total screen background colour except popup view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uicolor

I cant create saperate custom popview.. so I have tried like below mentioned one of the answer

**here is storyboard view hierarchy**

[image]

```
 popBG view background colour is black with alpha = 0.3
```

**this is code:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var popViewtop: UIView!    
@IBOutlet weak var testTable: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var popView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var popBG: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    popViewtop.isHidden = true
  
}

@IBAction func testBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    popViewtop.isHidden = false
}

@IBAction func btnPop(_ sender: Any) {
    
     let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewZoomAddressViewController") as! NewZoomAddressViewController;
    popViewtop.isHidden = true

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}
```

}

now the tableview and button are not showing transperently.. only popbg and popview coming.. did i miss anything..

[image]

**Actually i need like this**: total backgroundview in some darkcolour and popupview heighlighted in white colour

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your Popup view full screen ..which have background and have subview as popUp over that background ...so you dont need to change anything once you show or hide popup and its easy to implement... Full screen `UIView` having popUp `UIView` over it

You should have a view called it MainPopUpView ... in this view you will add two UIViews ...

1. Background View ... with black color with alpha 0.3
2. PopUpUI View ... which shows actual popup

```
                -> backGround UIView full screen  (with alpha 0.3) 
   MainPopUpView 
               -> popUpView short & centre and shows actual content
```

So MainPopUpView have two views ...

here is the hierarchy

[image]

Comment: i understood onething that if i change view alpha it effects on `popupvVew` as well... so what you want me to do i don't understand.. shall i create one more background view for `popupView`? can you please explain me in detail please

Comment: i cant create saperate custom popview... so i have created like your answer.. here everything works fine.. but the actual label and button in side popView are also coming blur why??

Comment: i have totally edited my post with your answer.. please have look

Comment: the only issue with label and button in popview.. plz do help.. i will accept and upvote for sure

Comment: dont add popView in popBG

Comment: i told you have a view .... add bg in it and add popup in it ... dont add popup in bg ... bg is different and popup is different .... in same view ... give bg view 0.3 alpha ... not the view holding both of them ....

Comment: i updated my answer with hierarchy please see that ...

Comment: sorry for disturbing again.. actually i got solution with your answer if i hide and show popBG and popView seperatly.. but if i give `hierarchy ` like above i am not getting.. where i am wrong

Comment: you dont need to show and hide them seperately ... just show and hide `MainPopup`

Comment: yes, if i show and hide main popup then it coming like abbove.. i updated post

Comment: you need to have ... `MainPopUp.backgroundcolor = .clear`

Comment: `bg.backgroundcolor = .black` and `bg.alpha = 0.3`

Answer (score 2):

1. if giving alpha value to view,

`view`'s subView's alpha value changes, including `popupView`

2. if giving background color to view, including `popupView`

`view`'s subView's alpha value does not change, including `popupView`

---

`popupView` is a subView of `view`,`view`'s alpha value affects its subviews's alpha.

```
view.addSubview(popupView)
```

***Your current structure:***

```
RootView->Subviews //Changing RootView alpha effects Subviews.
```

---

The solution is that the `popupView` is not a subview of `view` , which you show color changing with

Need a container view to separate from `popupView`

```
// backgroundColorChangeContainerView add other views ( tableView ... )
view.addSubview(backgroundColorChangeContainerView)
view.addSubview(popupView)
```

Comment: rather then adding and removing two views ... better way is to have one view with which have bg and popup ....

Comment: from the description , I think `popupView ` is just a small UI widget, not a custom `UIAlertController`.  Using a custom pop controller avoids this situation, and could not teach the question owner `view hierarchy`

Comment: the answers want me to create another bg view for popupView??

Comment: yes popupView is small UI only to show when i tap on button?? is there any other way to achieve like my final image.. `custom pop controller avoids this situation` how??.. i have edited my post with view hierarchy.. plz take a look

Comment: I saw an answer below

Answer (score 1):

other way to achieve like your final image.. `custom pop controller avoids this situation`

**put your `popupView`  in a custom viewController, then**

```
 @IBAction func addAddressBtn(_ sender: Any) {
       present(PopupViewController(nibName: "PopupViewController", bundle: nil), animated: true) {}
 }
```